# Django: Class based view can't render crispy form

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-crispy-forms

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I have trouble to render a crispy form with a class based view. Everything worked fine when I used the function based views.

As usual I generate forms.py as follows:

```
from django import forms    
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Submit, HTML, Button, Row, Field
from item.models import Item

class CreateItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ('user',)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_tag = False
            self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Fieldset(
                    'Create your item here',
                    'name', 'description', 
                    'save',
                ),
            )
            self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
            return super(CreateItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The view function is very simple and standard:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView,
from item.models import Item
from item.forms import CreateItemForm

class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateItemForm
    model = Item
    template_name = 'item/item_create_form.html'
```

and the template follows the minimal instructions as well:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Create new Item</h2>
            <form action="." class="crispy form-horizontal" method="post">
                {% crispy form form.helper %}
            </form>
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that Django will complain "VariableDoesNotExist at /item/add/, Failed lookup for key [helper] in ...".

**Are crispy forms compatible with class based views? How could I hand over the helper information to create the form correctly?**

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: can you provide more data of the traceback?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - Have a class based view and Crispy form parrallell to each other on same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735812/django-have-a-class-based-view-and-crispy-form-parrallell-to-each-other-on-sam)

Comment: Hi Nihal, looks like the other post is newer (only 15 days old). This was posted 8 months ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

constructor in your form is too indented, this way it belongs to form's `Meta` class, but it should be directly in `CreateItemForm`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the indentation was an issue. But now the complete form is rendered and not only the selected fields (name, description). How can I force the crispy form to focus on the fields in the Fieldset?

Comment: that's another issue, but try to remove `exclude` from form's `Meta` class

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it did not work. Still the full form is displayed. As a quick solution, I declared fields = ... under Meta, but that way, I can't modify the look of the form fields. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of showing exclude

```
fields ('field1','field2','field3')
```

here replace field1 and field2 and field3 with your field names. which you wanna show.this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What bit me was I left

> {{ form|crispy }}

instead of using

> % crispy form %}

The former will only emit Django's generic class based views