# Django - Have a class based view and Crispy form parrallell to each other on same page

Tags: python, html, django

Using Django, I am making a site that displays tickets. On the login page, I want it to where there is a preview area of existing tickets to the left of the login form. I am able to make both pages seperately, but I can not figure out how to make them co-exist side by side. I am also using jinja2 templating. I've been trying at this for 2 days, and I have read the tutorials over and over. Here is how I have it:

url.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'', include('ticket_app.urls')),
   url(r'^accounts/login/$', login, {'authentication_form': forms.LoginForm}, name='login'),
)
```

views.py Note: Request is the database table object:

```
class PreviewList(ListView):
    model = Request
```

form.py:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
    self.helper.form_tag = False
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('username', placeholder="Username", css_class='input-xlarge'),
        Field('password', placeholder="Password", css_class='input-xlarge'),
        FormActions(
            Submit('login', 'Login', css_class="btn-primary"),
        )
```

base.html(short version):

```
<h1>{% block page_title %}Preview of tickets{% endblock page_title %}</h1>
{%  block preview %}
{%  endblock preview %}

{%  block login %}
{%  endblock login %}
```

preview.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block preview %}
    <div class="span6">
    <ul class="list-group">
    {% if object_list %}
    {% for item in  object_list  %}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{item.date_due}} - {{item.desctription}}
    <span  class="badge">
        {% if item.user_assigned %}
        <span class="badge"style="color:green">  assigned  </span>
        {% else %}<span class="badge" style="color:red">unassigned</span>
        {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>Yay! No ticket requests found!</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock preview %}
```

login.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block login %}
    <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 70px;">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
                <div class="well">
                    <legend>Sign in to Site</legend>
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}" class="form-horizontal">
                        {% crispy form %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock login %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. For example, you could create your own login view that 'extends' the one from `django.contrib.auth`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

def login_with_preview(request, extra_context=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if extra_context is None:
        extra_context = {}
    extra_context['object_list'] = Request.objects.all()
    return login(request, authentication_form=LoginForm, extra_context=extra_context, *args, **kwargs)
```

And then use `login_with_preview` in your url conf and merge your two templates.

Another possibility is to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). This is especially nice if you want to show this preview list in different places:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("yourapp/preview_list.html")
def ticket_preview_list():
    return {'object_list': Request.objects.all()}
```

`preview_list.html` should *only* contain the template code that, right now, is in your `preview` template block. You need to make sure that template doesn't extend `base.html`; that would mess things up. The usual [template tag setup steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one view that renders the login form and the preview data

Comment: Will this have to be without Crispy Forms? I'm not having any success with __init__ which it seems Crispy Forms requires.